# TypeError: decoding str is not supported seen while calling function FieldDescriptor()

Tags: python

```
descriptor.FieldDescriptor(
      name='etag', full_name='ResponseContext.etag', index=2,
      number=3, type=9, cpp_type=9, label=1,
      has_default_value=False, default_value=str("", "utf-8"),
      message_type=None, enum_type=None, containing_type=None,
      is_extension=False, extension_scope=None,
      options=None),
```

Following error is seen for above function call:

```
has_default_value=False, default_value=str("", "utf-8"), TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: decoding str is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208812/typeerror-decoding-str-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not really have anything to do with calling `descriptor.FieldDescriptor`.

See the documentation for [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str):

> class str(object='')
>
> class str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
>
> Return a string version of object. If object is not provided, returns the empty string. Otherwise, the behavior of str() depends on whether encoding or errors is given, as follows.
>
> If neither encoding nor errors is given, str(object) returns object.__str__(), which is the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of object. For string objects, this is the string itself. If object does not have a __str__() method, then str() falls back to returning repr(object).
>
> **If at least one of encoding or errors is given, object should be a bytes-like object (e.g. bytes or bytearray).** In this case, if object is a bytes (or bytearray) object, then str(bytes, encoding, errors) is equivalent to bytes.decode(encoding, errors). Otherwise, the bytes object underlying the buffer object is obtained before calling bytes.decode(). See Binary Sequence Types — bytes, bytearray, memoryview and Buffer Protocol for information on buffer objects.
>
> Passing a bytes object to str() without the encoding or errors arguments falls under the first case of returning the informal string representation (see also the -b command-line option to Python). For example:

You are getting the error because of `str("", "utf-8")`. `""` is not a bytes-like object.

Comment: Actually i replaced Unicode with str seeing somewhere it is the replacement for unicode in python 3

Comment: Anyway, what you are trying to do is apparently `default_value=''`which of course pathologically could be written `default_value=str(b'', 'utf-8')` ... or `list(set(['', 'ignore', 'this']).intersection(set(['another', 'useless', 'set', ''])))[0]` or what have you.

Comment: I found a solution i just changed it to str("utf-8")