# Replace the order of parametrs of the function

Tags: python-3.x, string, types, typeerror

```
    # STEP 2 - FORMATNAME
    # Format Name -  takes in first and last name and  returns it as Last, First Name

    def format_name(first, last):
        # print("Student: TODO")
        str(last,first)
        return 

def main():
    print(format_name('Bill','Nye'))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I have to replace the order of parametrs of the function.

Comment: Hey, did you check that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208812/typeerror-decoding-str-is-not-supported. I think it is possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```py
def format_name(first, last):
    return last, first

last, first = format_name('John', 'Snow')
print(f"{last.strip()} {first.strip()}")  # Snow John
```

function returns two objects, which you can parse into two different variables. Then you can apply strip function on them.

Comment: I did the same thing but got an error "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'"

Comment: How i can solve this issue sir?

Comment: i have edited my answer.